# JDesktopPane e JInternalFrame en JAVA MVC con Listeners

Tags: java, mvc, java-swing

**
Hola buen día, en clases nos toco ver el patrón de diseño MVC para implementarlo en un proyecto a futuro.

Haciendo pruebas de como separar el código de las vistas y eso hice uno utilizando `JFrame -> 2 botones + JdesktopPane`; y cada botón abre un `JInternalFrame`, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema que tengo es cuando quiero escuchar un evento dentro de esos  `JInternalFrame`, no se como "escucharlos" ya que puse un botón dentro de cada `JInternalFram`e para que a la hora de presionarlos me regrese en consola un `sout` para saber que se presiono.

**Nombres de variables:**

Botón "Ventana 1" = **btnVentana1**

Botón "Ventana 2" = **btnVentana2**

JDesktopPane = **dpEscritorio**

Botón "Click me!" = **btnVentana1Frame**

Boton "Click me 2!" = **btnVentana2Frame**

Intente con:

```
if (e.getSource() == v1f.btnVentana1Frame) {
        System.out.println("Botón click me presionado");
    }
```

esperando que funcionara como funciono para abrir los JInternalFrames pero no me marca nada.

[image: Este es la estructura de mi proyecto (PrincipalModel esta vacio, solo lo puse para ocupar cada paquete)]

[image: PrincipalView]

[image: JInternalFrame 1]

[image: JInternalFrame 2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PrincipalController.java

```js
package controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import view.PrincipalView;
import view.Ventana1Frame;
import view.Ventana2Frame;

public class PrincipalController implements ActionListener{
    private PrincipalView pv;
    private Ventana1Frame v1f;
    private Ventana2Frame v2f;

    public PrincipalController(PrincipalView pv, Ventana1Frame v1f, Ventana2Frame v2f) {
        this.pv = pv;
        this.v1f = v1f;
        this.v2f = v2f;
        this.pv.btnVentana1.addActionListener(this);
        this.pv.btnVentana2.addActionListener(this);
        this.v1f.btnVentana1Frame.addActionListener(this);
        this.v2f.btnVentana2Frame.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void iniciar(){
        pv.setTitle("Prueba");
        pv.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pv.setVisible(true);
        v1f = null;
        v2f = null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Abrir Internal Frame 1
        if (e.getSource() == pv.btnVentana1) {
            if (v1f == null) {
            System.out.println("Ventana 1");
            v1f = new Ventana1Frame();
            pv.dpEscritorio.add(v1f);
            v1f.setVisible(true);
            } else {
            pv.dpEscritorio.getDesktopManager().activateFrame(v1f);
            }
        }
        
        //Abrir Internal Frame 2
        if (e.getSource() == pv.btnVentana2) {
            if (v2f == null) {
            System.out.println("Ventana 2");
            v2f = new Ventana2Frame();
            pv.dpEscritorio.add(v2f);
            v2f.setVisible(true);
            } else {
            pv.dpEscritorio.getDesktopManager().activateFrame(v2f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```js
package mvc;

import controller.PrincipalController;
import view.PrincipalView;
import view.Ventana1Frame;
import view.Ventana2Frame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrincipalView pv = new PrincipalView();
    Ventana1Frame v1f = new Ventana1Frame();
    Ventana2Frame v2f = new Ventana2Frame();
    
    PrincipalController pc = new PrincipalController(pv, v1f, v2f);
    pc.iniciar();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Te sugiero usar un solo controlador para todas las vistas y que este implemente todos los listener que necesites para manejar todos los eventos

Comment: @AndyC gracias por comentar, tomare el consejo, tienes idea de como seria el listener para manejar los eventos dentro de un JInternalFrame?, como el clic a un boton dentro de un JInternalFrame.

Comment: ¿Quién escucha las acciones de los botones en los internal frames?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes una solución, solo debes adaptarlas a tus requerimientos. Una clase que se encargue de escuchar todos los eventos que necesites.

```
public class ControladorPrincipal implements ActionListener, InternalFrameListener{
// puedes usar este controlador con todas las ventanas que quieras. A la final esta clase procesara todas las acciones que 
// esten en el implements que para simplicidad coloque ActionLister.(Botones)
// InternalFrameListener para cuando la ventana este activa, se este mostrando entre otros.


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // aqui colocas todo el codigo
}

@Override
public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

}
}
```

y aquí tienes una implementación simple. Puedes colocar las mismas en una clase de tu interes

```
JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame("Un Internal Frame 1");
JInternalFrame internal2 = new JInternalFrame("Un Internal Frame 2");
 // por simplicidad se obvia las partes de agregar elementos a estas ventanas y el proceso de empaquetarlos.

    ControladorPrincipal cp = new ControladorPrincipal();

    // Agregando el mismo controlador para ambas ventanas.
    // Puedes hacer lo mismo con otros elementos agregando mas listeners
    internal.addInternalFrameListener(cp);
    internal2.addInternalFrameListener(cp);
```